# Calling another function in PHP with Array as Parameter passing only first element (JSON RPC)

Tags: php, arrays, json, rpc

this might be quite a dummy question. I've been searching the web and trying around alot but i just can't find a solution.

I am sending out Core Data Objects as Dictionarys within an Array to my PHP JSON RPC web service. I will not dig further into this at this point, because i know that my JSON RPC is well formed.

On PHP side i do have one RPC Server which will take the JSON data and pass it to the respective function.

> $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

Using **print_r** i get the following result

> print_r($request['params']);

(Sorry, i don't know how to include 'Array (' and the closing ')' in the box)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [dayId] => 7
        [dayName] => Sonntag
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [dayId] => 6
        [dayName] => Samstag
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [dayId] => 4
        [dayName] => Donnerstag
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [dayId] => 2
        [dayName] => Dienstag
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [dayId] => 1
        [dayName] => Montag
    )

)
```

As mentioned before, this array is now passed to the respective function using

> $result = @call_user_func_array(array($object,$request['method']),$request['params']))

This will call method **updateDaysFromClient** in my implementation class.
At this point, i would like to repeat, that my JSON RPC is well formed (method, id, params).

> public function updateDaysFromClient($clientDaysArray) {
>
> print_r($clientDaysArray);
>
> return "Update test";
> }

Now comes my problem: Within my implementation, when calling the print_r on the array passed as parameter, i will only receive the first element of that array.

> Array
> (
>
> [dayId] => 7
>
> [dayName] => Sonntag
>
> )

Can anyone explain to me why not the whole Array but only the first element is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to pass like this,

```
$result = @call_user_func_array(array($object,$request['method']),array($request['params'])))
```

pass $request['params'] inside another array.

Comment: Hi Manadh, it works. Thank you alot! Right now im waiting for the timer to allow me to accept your question:) Why is it necessary to pass one array into another array though?

Comment: since we are using call_user_func_array it accepts param and method in the form of array

Comment: function call_user_func_array accepts param in the form of array